# threejs: Does anyone know what happened to phong/standard shading support on recent (Nougat) smartphone releases of Android?

Tags: android, three.js, glsl, webgl, phong

i.e., MeshPhongMaterial, MeshStandardMaterial.  These materials now render as black.

Examples: 
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_teapot

In the last example, only "Wireframe" and "Smooth" of the Shading menu work on many recent low-cost phones.  Is this because these phones don't support GLSL?  Is it a GPU problem or a battery life problem such that the manufacturers are disabling support?

Sorry if there's a long explanatory thread somewhere here already; I couldn't find it.

Comment: This can be a bug of threee.js or a bug or change in mobile Chrome. I'm not a regular user of three.js but, have you checked if there's a bug filed on the github project?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox on Android to see if it has the same problem? Have you tried checking out an old version of three.js and seeing if they used to work or have they always been broken? It's most likely they're using features those phones do not support. You should connect your phone to your computer and [run the Chrome JavaScript tools remotely](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to see if they report any errors.